# What is better for unique results : Set or Projection in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I know two ways to get unique/distinct data list in hibernate. I can get unique/distinct data list using projection or convert data list to a set in hibernate criteria.

```
Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>(crt.list());
```

Should I use Set over projection to get unique data list?

Thanks in advance

---

Hi,
I got the solution, now sharing for all. We should fetch smaller data list from db and it is faster. So I think we should use Projection. But now I implemented this as follows:

```
Criteria crt = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);    
crt.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
List<User> users = crt.list(); // fetch distinct User list
```

I used Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY instead of Projection.